# Ratios in a triangle.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In triangle $ABC$, $S$ is a point on side $BC$ such that $BS:SC=1:2$, and $T$ is a point on side $AC$ such that $AT:TC=4:3$ .  Let U be the intersection of $AS$ and $BT$.  Find $AU:US$.

I would appreciate any ideas as to how approach this problem. I set equations using position vectors, but I cannot figure out a way how to write vector $u$ ( position vector of point $U$) in terms of given sides. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be using vectors, but I have a synthetic solution for you:
Apply [Menelaus' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menelaus%27_theorem) to $\triangle ASC$ with transversal $U-B-T$ to get
$$\frac{AU}{US}\times\frac{SB}{BC}\times\frac{CT}{TA}=-1$$
Since $\dfrac{BS}{SC}=\dfrac12$, $\dfrac{SB}{BC}=-\dfrac13$ (note that the ratios use directed distances over here).
Also $\dfrac{CT}{TA} = \dfrac34$ as is given.
Plugging these values into the above equation,
$\dfrac{AU}{US}=\dfrac41$.

Answer (score 2):

Your notation and data gives a figure of the shape below.

Menelaus' theorem is suitable for use here but leaving of side the original triangle and taking one of the new two triangles  $\Delta CTB$ or $\Delta CAS$ with transversal lines respectively  $AS$ and $BT$. The convenient here is the second one which cross the three sides $AS$, $AC$ and $CS$  at the points $U$,$T$ and $B$ respectively.

We have then $\frac{CB}{BS}\cdot$ $\frac{SU}{UA}\cdot$ $\frac{AT}{TC} = 1$ that is,
$\frac31\cdot$$\frac{SU}{UA}\cdot$$\frac43 = 1$ and finally $\frac{AU}{US}=4$

NOTE.- Usually Menelaus' theorem (not too comfortable for the geometric intuition at first sight) goes with signed lengths of segments with some fixed orientation what is proper of projective geometry; it was not necessary here  (with the other triangle $\Delta CTB$, Menelaus gives $\frac{BU}{UT}=\frac78$).

[image]

Comment: You can only use Menelaus on $\triangle CAS$ (to answer OP's question). The other triangle $\triangle CTB$ has a ratio that is not known a priori. It can be used to find $\dfrac{BU}{UT}$ _after_ having computed $\dfrac{AU}{US}$.

Comment: @cmtappu96: $\frac{CA}{AT}\cdot$$\frac{TU}{UB}\cdot$$\frac{BS}{SC}=1$. I repeat: it is not too comfortable to geometric intuition. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

hint: make $SE//BT, E$ on $AC$